# Removing Custom url from github.io

Tags: git, github

I have created a github page: isha97.github.io. I added a custom url to it and removed it later. Now when I try to open isha97.github.io, it redirects to the custom url. I have checked my repo for any CNAME file. It doesn't have any CNAME file. Should I delete my repo and make it again?

Comment: did you gave enough time to propagate changes through DNS? it may take up to 24h

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the repo. just create a new branch using github web interface, type gh-pages and press enter:

[image]

Now go to your repo's settings, and change github pages source to gh-pages.:
[image]

This will automatically clears any cache or dns issues...

**Update**
@Isha, I just checked your website and its working fine: https://isha97.github.io/

Sometimes github page may take a while to get updated while performing cname changes. See this page form more info on troubleshooting the domains: https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses a `301` redirect for custom domains. Your browser still has the redirect cached. Try opening a nonexistent URL on your GitHub Pages site and setting a cookie. Then, clear the cache for your site in your browser settings.